# Internal error no wrapping name for empty structure codegen maven jibx plugin?

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, jibx, maven-jibx

i am trying to generate jibx classes from XSD, i see error while generating the classes here is the stack trace

[image]

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error - no
> wrapping name for empty structure
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.addToBinding (StructureClassHolder.java:1782)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.generate (StructureClassHolder.java:2150)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.PackageHolder.generate (PackageHolder.java:210)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.ClassHolder.initClass (ClassHolder.java:697)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.generate (StructureClassHolder.java:2111)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.PackageHolder.generate (PackageHolder.java:210)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.PackageHolder.generate (PackageHolder.java:227)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.buildDataModel (CodeGen.java:1572)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.generate (CodeGen.java:1781)
> at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.main (CodeGen.java:2206)
> at org.jibx.maven.AbstractCodeGenMojo.execute (AbstractCodeGenMojo.java:271)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (ethod.java:498)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Comment: What happens when you try one of the JiBX maven samples? For example: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/basic.html

Comment: @DonCorley Both codegen and compile is working fine for other XSD's of mine,  not working for specific xsd i feel issue is with XSD